# vpnc -- restart after dhcp renew

Tags: dhcp, vpnc

I am running Xubuntu 17.10 with vpnc installed (version 0.5.3r550-3)

Everytime dhclient runs my vpnc connection fails:

From /var/log/syslog

```
[...] dhclient[26917]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to [...]
[...] dhclient[26917]: DHCPREQUEST of [...]
[...] dhclient[26917]: DHCPOFFER of [...]
[...] dhclient[26917]: DHCPACK of [...]
...
[...] vpnc[26788]: esp sendto: Message too long
```

After that i have to manually run, else it does not work anymore

```
sudo vpnc-disconnect
sudo vpnc
```

Can i automate that?

Edit:

what I have found out so far is that dhclient calls /sbin/dhclient-script and this updates /etc/resolv.conf based on received values -- which are different what vpnc sets.

Maybe a solution would be to set static values here and prevent dhclient to overwrite the settings in /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: while I'm waiting for this answer to be moved to "Unix & Linux" and marked as a duplicate, here's the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269567/better-method-for-acting-on-ip-address-change-from-the-isp

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same problem but it works if i create the file  /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ufw where i run `/usr/sbin/vpnc-disconnect && /usr/sbin/vpnc` -- i will so some tests

Comment: in case my answer is OK, can you please accept it?

Comment: Sure. But first let me try this tomorrow on my production system

Comment: @TomášPospíšek It is okay if there is crosspost.  While I'm not a *fan* of it, there is overlap between here and Unix and Linux, and the two different communities can help provide other answers that the other wouldn't have considered or such.  As such, I am rejecting the migration request.  (To migrate and then close as a dupe would bounce it back here and close it as offtopic, anyways, but it's on topic at both places.  So I'm leaving this alone).  Also, your non-answer answer (link-only answers are not considered sufficient on their own) has been converted to a comment.